# running onload function in Google Form app script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google Form and a script and a script bound to the form.
I'm trying to get a function to run when a user fill in the form.

But the only function I get to run is when a hook it to the OnFormSubmit trigger.
No other function is running, no matter what I try.

Can I run a function i Google App Script on initial load when a user is filling the form? Is this possible?

Thanks

---

*More details (I'll accept some other way to accomplish the task):*

*the function should capture some url parameters I pass to the form, and send it over to Google Analytics... I believe that part is solved here: [Google Forms & The Measurement Protocol](http://online-behavior.com/analytics/measurement-protocol)*

*As the form has several pages, the parameters I pass to the first page gets lost when the user goes to next pages, so I cannot capture them when submitting the form - therefore I'm trying to do it whenever the users first edits the form.*

*I tried to add the params as prefilled fields on a hidden page, but if it is hidden then it too gets lost on submitting...*

Comment: What you are asking for is not possible with a Google Form.  You would need to create an  Apps Script Web App and design your own input form with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

Comment: @SandyGood thanks for your comments. I'll accept it as correct answer if nobody else has anything to add...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Sandy did not write out an answer, I will.

You cannot execute Apps Script as part of a form when the user visits it. You can't modify a form as the user is filling it out (Dynamic form...etc). If you need this type of behavior, you will need to create your own form as part of a Apps Script Web App.

Web App information: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web